# Laravel Route model binding - empty user

Tags: laravel-5, binding, ioc-container

I have a route

```
http://192.168.10.15/user/33/edit
```

I am trying to return the user based on the url id.

```
  public function edit($id, \App\User $user)
    {
        dd($user->id);
         return view('user.update');

    }
```

The id is returning null, how do I do this?

Comment: For anyone who lands here, note that the variable name is case-sensitive...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For route binding to work you should have type-hinted variable names match a route segment name, as the doc required :

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or
>   controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route
>   segment name. For example:
>
> ```
> Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
> return $user->email; });
> ```
>
> Since the $user variable is type-hinted as the App\User Eloquent model
>   and the variable name matches the {user} URI segment, Laravel will
>   automatically inject the model instance that has an ID matching the
>   corresponding value from the request URI. If a matching model instance
>   is not found in the database, a 404 HTTP response will automatically be generated.

For your case :

```
Route::get('/users/{user}/edit', 'YourController@edit');
```

And in your controller :

```
public function edit(\App\User $user)
{
     dd($user->id);
     return view('user.update')->withUser($user);

}
```

Comment: If your model has an alias in the import inside controller, like `use Models/VeryLongModelNameDoe as Doe` you should use `Route::get('/{doe}, 'DoeController@edit')` in the route model binding, otherwise, you will get an empty Model.

Answer (score 14):

If you recently upgraded to laravel 5.3 and above, you might want to check if you have updated `laravel/app/Http/Kernel.php` to register route middleware for binding substitution.

> Route model binding is now accomplished using middleware. All
>   applications should add the 
>   Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings to your web
>   middleware group in your app/Http/Kernel.php file:
>
> ```
> \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
> ```
>
> You should also register a route middleware for binding substitution
>   in the $routeMiddleware property of your HTTP kernel:
>
> ```
> 'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
> ```
>
> Once this route middleware has been registered, you should add it to
>   the api middleware group:
>
> ```
> 'api' => [
>     'throttle:60,1',
>     'bindings',
> ],
> ```

Comment: you can debug in the model src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php::resolveRouteBinding

Comment: my problem was that i forgot to add `api middleware` to my custom router

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding named route. Model binding didn't work if there was no name specified for route.

```
Route::get('product/{product}', "ProductController@read")->name('product.read');
```